# Avoiding redirect landing page no one give a solution

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, web-hosting

Unfortunately until no one give an answer or solution for this problem ! 
i have contact my webhost company and they said maybe from theme or plugins i have deactivate it them all even the theme but still the same problem i have check my wp-options and site name setup correct i have google it and no solution . can anybody had this problem and he found the solution to share it with me

```
http://beautysecrets.ro/
http://www.beautysecrets.ro/
https://www.beautysecrets.ro/
```

---

htaccess :

```
# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how i can avoid this redirects ? i have delete these codes from htaccess file and still have the same problem .

Comment: By removing all the `RewriteRule` from htaccess. It is still unclear what you mean.

Comment: i deleted the codes which is up ! on my comment from my htaccess code and i check again but i still have the same problem of redirects

Comment: Clear your browser history, or try this in a private window. 301 redirects get cached by browsers.

Comment: this showing on gtmatrix so its not about my browser cache